# Automatically Updating Modules ( eg DLLs ) Committed to TFS where it is needed

Tags: visual-studio, dll, tfs, version-control, dependencies

Here is the information about the development environment pertaining to my work computer:

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.35123.00 Update 2

Here is an high-level view of how our TFS repository, and projects are setup:

[image]

In the current setup, it's difficult to keep up-to-date DLLs that the Dependent project needs.
We have to ensure that developers who make changes to the ProviderSolution also generate dlls, and manually check-in the said dlls to the DependantSolution's TFS directory.

Could someone please explain how I could go about automating the aforementioned process in TFS?

Answer (score 1):

You can [create and publish a Nuget package](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package) in ProviderSolution, then DependentSolution's projects can depend on that package. When you build DependentSolution, the nuget package will automatically restore the latest version.

Comment: When the DependentSolution is built, is it possible for nuget package to automatically restore the latest version of the ProviderSolution's projects as some kind of generated dll from TFS itself?  If yes, may I please know how I would go about doing this?